# What does the level 3 boss say?

Tags: bad-dudes-vs-dragonninja

At the end of level 3 of this classic arcade game you fight the green ninja, a boss who can split into multiple copies of himself.

Before he does this, he says.. something.

Does anyone know what he says?  (and preferably an English translation, as my Japanese is a little rusty)

Comment: I didn't know the game before but now I really want to know what he says too :/ You mean the "Owanjitsuac" sounding thing, right?

Comment: Aye, that's it.  If I find out that it's just gibberish, I'm going to squeal!

Comment: should go to the japanese language SE chat and ask them to come take a look

Answer (score 2):

> Sho daijitsu wasu

It means "multiple targets", or in that context it's the spell name or action he is using to multiply himself.

Answer (score -1):

According to this video:

nothing?

It seems it's the protagonist character saying "I'm Bad!".

Comment: It's the bit at 2:08.  The level 3 boss.

Comment: That sounds like non-English, maybe Japanese, with some reverb. It also sounds like he says it repeatedly, once each time he makes clones.

Comment: I want to downvote the text and upvote the video.

Answer (score -1):

Considering most of the sound effects in the game seem to be either english or just screams and effects, I'm going to assume the ninja is speaking in English as well.

Based on that, the best I can do is hearing '*Watch this one!*' as if he's about to show you something kickass. (Which he does, he clones himself a bunch of times)

Comment: By the same token, you could say that Ryu is saying "How do, Ken?" in Street Fighter 2.  

I'm hoping a Japanese speaker can give me a definitive answer to the question that's been bugging me for the last 25(!) years.

Comment: First of all, your example doesn't make sense in the context of the game. Why would a guy ask how someone is doing when shooting an energy blast? When not even facing that guy? Second of all, it's not even certain what language the ninja is speaking in. But to each his own I guess.

Comment: I'm assuming, as it's an 80s ninja game, that the guy is speaking Japanese but as my question indicates, I really have no idea.   I know what he's saying -sounds like- (and can do a chillingly accurate version myself) but after all this time, I just want someone to give me a definite answer. I'd hate to go to my grave with this still unknown.